# Етимологія "ціґеле-міґеле" / "сіґеле-міґеле"

Tags: переклад, етимологія

Зараз набирає популярності [пісня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_Pep6MW1wc) "сіґеле-міґеле" гурту NAZVA.

Намагаюся знайти, звідки пішло це "сіґеле", і не можу зрозуміти, чи-то воно від нім. Ziegel - цегла, чи-то від нім. Ziege - коза.

Також не до кінця зрозуміло, чи "міґеле" - це просто редуплікація, чи також слово зі значенням.

Answer (score 6):

На сайті [IsraelCulture.info](https://www.israelculture.info/cigele-migele-skazka-o-beloj-kozochke/) знайшов ґіфку (перша на сторінці), де підгледів, як це слово пишеться на їдиші:

[image: Tsigele-Migele]

Вбив у ґуґл варіант на їдиші й знайшов сайт з наступного абзацу.

На сайті [InGeveb.org](https://ingeveb.org/texts-and-translations/yiddishists) знайшов статтю із перекладом (паралельним текстом) тексту Йозефа Тункеля *Їдишисти: монолоґ єврея з Києва*.

У тексті є таке речення:

> און אין דער אמתן, ווי קען מען זינגען "פֿייגעלע, פֿייגעלע, פּי, פּי, פּי," אָדער "**ציגעלע מיגעלע** קאָטינקע," ווען מען האָט נישט קיין דיפּלאָם אויף לכל־הפּחות אַכט קלאַסן קאָנסערוואַטאָריע?

Де ציגעלע מיגעלע — це і є *ціґеле-міґеле*.

А ось переклад англійською:

> And indeed, who would dare to sing “Little Bird, Little Bird, Peep Peep Peep” or “Little **Goatie-Moatie**, Kitty-Cat” without a diploma certifying that you’ve completed at least eight years of conservatory studies?

Goatie-Moatie — це, якщо зовсім у лоба, то *коза-моза*, а якщо по-нашому, то щось типу ***коза-дереза*** або *кізонька-дерізонька*, адже *ле* в німецькій/їдиші або *ie* в англійській — це зменшувально-пестливий суфікс.

Тому, думаю, ціґеле-міґеле — це коза-дереза. І походить воно з їдишу.

Answer (score 5):

> <sub>[*Агатангел Кримський*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87): [Розвідки, статті та замітки. Ⅰ-ⅩⅩⅦ](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2FE_LIB%2FPDF%2Fukr0002383.pdf) → Калач-малач, кішміш-мішміш → Ⅲ</sub>
>
> [с. 148:] вираз: **ціґеле-міґеле:** *ціґеле* = коза, *міґеле* нічого не значить, а разом *ціґеле-міґеле* значить: *коза і т. и*.

> <sub>[Словник *їдиш-анґлійська*](//cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi) на сайтї [універсітета Кентукі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%96) і підписано як джерела [Рафаела Фінкела](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_Finkel) до їдиша</sub>
>
> **tsig** *noun, plural in* -n, *has diminutive, gender f*, «goat» tsikele *noun, plural in* -kh, «young goat» source: [Stutchkoff](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Stutchkoff)

Щодо самої етімолоґії:

> <sub>Wiktionary</sub>
>
> [**ציגל**](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%92%D7%9C) це [ציג‎ (tsig)](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%92#Yiddish) «коза» + демінутів [־ל‎ (-l)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D6%BE%D7%9C#Yiddish)
>
> ---
>
> **ציג**‎ (tsig) ← [середньоверхньонімецька] *zige* ← [давньоверхньонімецька] *ziga*, from [протозахідноґеманська] [**tigā*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/tig%C4%81).
>
> ---
>
> **־ל**‎ (-l) ← [давньоверхньонімецька] *-ilī*. Пор. [нїмецька] *-lein*, [[алеманська](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)] *-li*.